# How to save a state in Shared preferences on Android Java?

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

In my application after login I have to save state in shared preference to change the app view on a button click. can anyone help me to save state in shared Preferences and on a button click i need to replace the initial state with the new one.

Comment: Why do you want to save the layout? Could you please elaborate? you can use shared preference to maintain the login state not to save the layout.

Comment: Saving layout is not a good practice we use shared preference to save some data not the layouts

Comment: @Aman, Is it possible to save ImageButton and TextView in sharedPreferences anh how can we go it?

Comment: @abdul it is not possible to save layouts using shared preference.

Comment: @Aman, then how can i change ui when a button is pressed

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can't save a layout.  You can save a layout id-  but I wouldn't suggest it.  Resource ids are not stable across builds, so any update would break it.  Your best bet is to create an enum with whatever values you wish it to have, save the enum, and later on convert the string back into an enum when you read it in.  Then hold a map<enum, resourceId> in code that maps to the correct resource id.